# How to make a single column scrollable in jquery data table when column is overflowed with data?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, datatables, thymeleaf

I have used jquery data-table to show my list in table. But sometimes for a single id I have to print multiple data in a single column. As a result my column become bigger. So I want to make that column scroll-able if the column is over-flowed with data. [image]

In column `Files` , I have multiple files for a single column. I want to make that column scroll-able when there are several file. Is it possible? In my html I wrote java-script code for jquery table is

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#currentAcrTable").DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [

                { "targets": [1,2,3,4,5], "searchable": false },
                { "width": "15%", "targets": 4 }
            ]
        });
        $("#oldAcrTable").DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

And my html code for iterating loop and showing data is

```
 <tr th:each="acr : ${list}">
                        <td th:text="${acr.govtId}" align="center"></td>
                        <td th:text="${acr.year}" align="center"></td>
                        <td th:text="${acr.assigned_from}" align="center"></td>
                        <td th:text="${acr.assigned_to}" align="center"></td>


                        <td align="center">

                            <div class="scroll_y" style="overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">
                            <span th:each="file: ${acr.filelist}">
                                <a href=""><img th:src="@{/images/pdf-icon.png}" width="15px" height="15px"/></a>
                            </span>
                            </div>

                        </td>
    </tr>
```

I added  `<div class="scroll_y" style="overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">` inside `td` according to the answer of Joseph_J. But no changes

Comment: You just want any cell that is overflowed with data to scroll?

Comment: Yes ! In my table `Files`  column can be over-flowed. So I want to make this column scroll-able only .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a cell that lands in the file column you can add some overflow properties.

I have read that the table cells themselves don't handle overflow well.  It's is recommended that you place a div in the cell and then style the div.

Like so:

```
<td>
  <div style="width:50px; height:50px; overflow-y:scroll;">To much data, this cell needs to scroll.</div>
</td>
```

In the above code I added inline styling to add the scroll properties for the div.

You can also create a css class containing your scroll properties.  I believe that you can use the dataTables properties to define a class for a specific column.

CSS:

```
.scroll_y{

  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

HTML:

```
<td>
  <div class="scroll_y">To much data, this cell needs to scroll.</div>
</td>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Haven't got expected result :(

Comment: You added the css to your css script and changed your jquery.  Did it make any changes at all.  The html was just an example of how to apply the css.

Comment: I used inline style and defined `class="scroll_y"` inside `div` tag

Comment: How is your html being generated?

Comment: A really good way to trouble shoot this is to inspect your table.  You should be able to make changes to your html and see how they change things on your page directly from the inspector.  Then when you get something that works make those changes in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186216/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-avijit-barua).

Answer (score 1):

Please try giving this style to your td that you want to be scroll-able 
You can give it the fixed height according to your requirement

```
style=" height:40px ;  overflow-y: scroll; display: block"
```

Check this link for reference

https://codepen.io/singhagam1/pen/MZVrrJ

Comment: Sorry For a lot of edits but this will surely work . cheers !